# Flip texture in DirectX9 (Managed)

Tags: textures, flip, managed-directx

I need to flip the texture vertically or horizontally. I use the following code for this:

```
        //We are use textures Format.X8R8G8B8, so            
        int bytesPerPixel = 4;

        int pitch;
        GraphicsStream srcGs = srcTexture.LockRectangle ( 0, LockFlags.ReadOnly, out pitch );
        GraphicsStream dstGs = dstTexture.LockRectangle ( 0, LockFlags.None );

        for ( int y = 0; y < h; y++ )
            for ( int x = 0; x < w; x++ )
            {
                byte [ ] buffer = new byte[ bytesPerPixel ];
                srcGs.Seek ( y * pitch + x * bytesPerPixel, SeekOrigin.Begin );
                srcGs.Read ( buffer, 0, bytesPerPixel );
                if ( flag == FlipTextureFlags.Horizontal )
                    dstGs.Seek ( ( h - y ) * pitch + x * bytesPerPixel, SeekOrigin.Begin );
                else
                    dstGs.Seek ( y * pitch + ( w - x ) * bytesPerPixel, SeekOrigin.Begin );
                dstGs.Write ( buffer, 0, bytesPerPixel );
            }
        srcTexture.UnlockRectangle ( 0 );
        dstTexture.UnlockRectangle ( 0 );
```

The code works great, but there are a lot of textures and their size can be up to 1200x2600. Because the flip is made dynamically, the program's performance is reduced. Is there any other way to flip the texture? Or how to maintain performance? (I do not use shaders)

Comment: You can always flip the UV coordinates you draw with instead.

Comment: No I can't. As incoming param I have complete texture ( typeof(Texture) ), so...